# Get credential directly from Token Vending Machine

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb

Before I begin, the question I will ask may be considered 'newbie', however due to the lack of time I need help and cannot find a simple answer through most documentation provided. 
I have hosted the anonymous token vending machine successfully. Tried running AWSiOSDemoTVM iOS app successfully.

Now I am trying to write small app which will insert few records to a `dynamodb` test table. Unfortunately the provided `AWSiOSDemoTVM` doesn’t demonstrate any dynamodb features. I tried other examples too. But difficult to understand.

I have the following sample code which works great if I hardcode the credentials.

Can anybody provide me sample code to get the credentials returned by `AnonymousTVM client` so that I can replace hardcoded credentials with this.

```
AmazonCredentials *creds = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY];
AmazonDynamoDBClient *ddb = [[AmazonDynamoDBClient alloc] initWithCredentials:creds];
NSString *ddbendpoint = [AmazonEndpoints ddbEndpoint:US_WEST_2];

DynamoDBPutItemRequest *putItemRequest = [DynamoDBPutItemRequest new];
[putItemRequest setRequestEndpoint:ddbendpoint];
putItemRequest.tableName = @"UserTable";

DynamoDBAttributeValue *value = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:@"1006"];
[putItemRequest.item setValue:value forKey:@"UserId"];

value = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithS:@"Recod-No-6"];
[putItemRequest.item setValue:value forKey:@"RecordId"];

value = [DynamoDBAttributeValue new];
[value addSS:@"Green"];
[value addSS:@"Red"];
[value addSS:@"Black"];
[putItemRequest.item setValue:value forKey:@"Colors"];

@try {
    DynamoDBPutItemResponse *putItemResponse = [ddb putItem:putItemRequest];
    NSLog(@"Consumed write capacity for putItem: %d", [putItemResponse.consumedCapacity.capacityUnits integerValue]);
    NSLog(@"putItem httpStatusCode: %d",putItemResponse.httpStatusCode);
}
@catch (DynamoDBResourceNotFoundException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.errorCode);
}
```

---

**UPDATE :-**

I found the following way to get the credentials.
Is this correct ?.

```
AmazonCredentials *credentials = [AmazonKeyChainWrapper getCredentialsFromKeyChain];
if (! credentials){
    NSLog(@"-----> no credentials");
    [AmazonClientManager validateCredentials];
    credentials = [AmazonKeyChainWrapper getCredentialsFromKeyChain];
}

//NSLog(@"  %@",credentials.access) ;
AmazonDynamoDBClient *ddb = [[AmazonDynamoDBClient alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials];
ddb.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints ddbEndpoint:US_WEST_2];
```